# Error installing php-5.4.9. on OSX

Tags: macos, installation, php

I have tried to install php 5.4.9 a few times and I can't seem to understand the problem. Here is the error of the installation of process and it did came with a report which I sent my email I am uncertain in when will they reply on it.

```
=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test open_basedir configuration [tests/security/open_basedir_linkinfo.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: BUG: open_basedir cannot delete symlink to prohibited file. See also
bugs 48111 and 52176.
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #63336 (invalid E_NOTICE error occur) [Zend/tests/bug63336.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug is not fixed yet
Initial value of static var in method depends on the include time of the class definition [Zend/tests/method_static_var.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Maybe not a bug
DateTime::add() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
Bug #53437 (Crash when using unserialized DatePeriod instance) [ext/date/tests/bug53437.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug #53437 Not fixed yet
Bug #62852 (Unserialize invalid DateTime causes crash) [ext/date/tests/bug62852.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: bug is not fixed yet
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: RFC not implemented yet
Bug #42718 (unsafe_raw filter not applied when configured as default filter) [ext/filter/tests/bug42718.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW not applied when configured as default filter, even with flags
Bug #60634 (Segmentation fault when trying to die() in SessionHandler::write()) [ext/session/tests/bug60634.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Long term low priority bug, working on it
Bug #60634 (Segmentation fault when trying to die() in SessionHandler::write()) - fatal error in write during exec [ext/session/tests/bug60634_error_1.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Long term low priority bug, working on it
Bug #60634 (Segmentation fault when trying to die() in SessionHandler::write()) - exception in write during exec [ext/session/tests/bug60634_error_2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Long term low priority bug, working on it
Bug #60634 (Segmentation fault when trying to die() in SessionHandler::write()) - fatal error in write after exec [ext/session/tests/bug60634_error_3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Long term low priority bug, working on it
Bug #60634 (Segmentation fault when trying to die() in SessionHandler::write()) - exception in write after exec [ext/session/tests/bug60634_error_4.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Long term low priority bug, working on it
Bug #45712 (NaN/INF comparison) [ext/standard/tests/math/bug45712.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug 45712 not fixed yet.
=====================================================================
```

Note that I am installing OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error as such, this is exactly what it says, an Expected Failed Test Summary. You should complete installation by typing:

```
sudo make install
```

<update>

I found this excellent blog posting called [Mac OS X Lion - Upgrade to PHP 5.4](http://www.hirmet.com/mac-os-x-lion-upgrade-to-php-5-4). I would recommend starting completely over, and following the instructions posted.

Not knowing all that you did to get thus far, I can't really comment on what went wrong and why it won't go any further.

</update>

Comment: That's the command I did which gave me this.

Comment: Okay. Did you try to install?

Comment: Yes, I also tried install gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://php-osx.liip.ch/ if you just need a recent PHP version.